# Telesign SMS body truncated after '@'

Tags: sms

I am using TeleSign [SEND SMS](https://enterprise.telesign.com/api-reference/apis/sms-api/send-an-sms/post-messaging) API and in the SMS body if I include `@` symbol the SMS body is truncated.
For example:
if SMS Body is:

> Send us an email at: customersupport@domainname.com

Then the user would receive:

> Send us an email at: customersupport

How do I include Special characters like `@` in the SMS body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was at the backend side of the TeleSign which has been resolved after opening a ticket with their support team.